# Four fair six-sided dice are rolled. What is the probability that at least three of the four dice show the same?

Tags: probability

We can choose any value for the first one, so... $1 \times \frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6} + (\frac{1}{6})^3$ will be equal to the answer. But this doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Wait why minus -1, what did I do wrong though?

Comment: Is my problem hard to understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should break up the problem into pieces. First let's compute how many ways we can get exactly three of the dice to show the same number. First we choose which three dice we are forcing to have the same value (namely $4\choose 3$) and multiply this by the number of values the three dice can have (there are 6 possibilities here). Then multiply this by all possible values for the fourth dice (this is 5 since we can't have the last die have the same value as the first 3). This gives a total of $5\times 6\times$$4\choose 3 $$=120$ possibilities.

Now we add the above to the number of ways all four dice land on the same number - there are only 6 ways.

There are a total of $6^4 = 1296$ possible configurations of the four dice. The probability you want is $\frac{126}{1296} = \frac{7}{72}$ giving about a $9.7$% chance of this occurring.

Comment: That sounds about right: https://ideone.com/xrBwoV

Comment: How do you verify the answer? All I saw is codes

Comment: @silva, nice answer for me. It is easy for me to see why.

Comment: Thanks Valkyrie. When dealing with general counting problems, always try to break it down into pieces, and be sure to not only include all cases, but also not to double count.

Comment: @Valkyrie Output is at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can have four the same, with probability $\frac 6{6^4}$  because there are six combinations available.  You can have exactly three match, which is $6$ (pick the number to have three of) $5$ (pick the odd number) $4$ (pick which will be the three of a kind)$/6^4$, giving $\frac {6+6\cdot 5 \cdot 4}{6^4}=\frac 7{72}$

Comment: Ross, why did it this way.

Comment: Because it works.  We don't want to quadruple count the cases with all four the same because all the sets of three match.

Comment: Your first term counts the chance the first three dice will match (and allows the fourth to be anything).  Your second term counts the chance all four are the same.  All four the same was already counted in the first term, so is counted twice.  You have missed the cases where the odd die is in the first three.